# how to turn off or supress maven test loading messages

Tags: maven, junit, maven-3, junit4

i am using maven to run my tests. when the test runs, there are a lot of useless (to me for now, at least) messages outputted to the console. my pom.xml has the following plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.15</version>
 <configuration>
  <includes>
   <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
  </includes>
  <systemPropertyVariables>
  <log4j.configuration>file:${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/log4j.properties</log4j.configuration>
  </systemPropertyVariables>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

when i run

```
mvn clean test
```

i see the a bunch of messages that look like the following.

```
[parsing started RegularFileObject[...]]
[search path for source files: ...]
[search path for class files: ...]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[...]]
```

how do i turn these off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's how i resolved it. the problem was with setting the compilation to verbose (e.g. java -verbose). in my pom.xml, i made

```
<verbose>true</verbose>
```

to

```
<verbose>false</verbose>
```

in the build/plugins/plugin section of my pom.xml, the following is what i have now.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.0</version>
 <configuration>
  <compilerArguments>
   <Xlint />
  </compilerArguments>
  <verbose>false</verbose>
  <source>${java.version}</source>
  <target>${java.version}</target>
  <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

so those "useless" outputs had nothing to do with the surefire plugin, but instead, with the configuration of the compiler plugin.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how these messages are printed from your code. If they are printed with System.out.println() you will likely not be able to suppress them. If LOG4J is used, you can put the following *log4j.xml* to *src/test/resources* or your project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="devnull" class="org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender"/>
    <root>
        <priority value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="devnull"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I'm using this approach in my project and it works pretty well. However it can depend on whether you have any other log4j.xml in your classpath (for example in src/main/resources). If yes - additional work will be required to make sure log4j picks up right configuration file for unit test environment.

Comment: i am not doing any System.out.print's. it seems to be that these messages are outputted from the maven surefire plugin when it scans for classes and jars to run the tests. but i have to agree that it seems these are System.out.print messages since their output do not resemble what's been define in log4j.properties or logback.xml. by the way i did try to put in that log4j.xml file into my src/test/resources folder, but that didn't help. now i have to wonder, if it's true, why are they using System.out.println and why on such seemingly useless messages.

Comment: well, i just found out that those messages can be produced by "javac -verbose". i turned it off per http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html and now those output goes away.

Comment: Goot to know you've resolved it. I think it's worth to put an answer here and accept it so other people see the right one.